# Devise + email confirmation token, to set initial password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

devise (3.2.4) rails (3.2.17) and cancan (1.6.10)

Admin creates other users. So in `RegistrationsController` I have

```
before_filter :check_permissions, :only => [:new, :create]
skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication

def check_permissions
    authorize! :create, resource
end
```

`new and create` actions as well.

I'm finding it difficult to follow [confirmable](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb) and some through SO questions.

How to call **generate_confirmation_token** for the signed up user,and email the *link* using **confirmation_url**, should I use `ConfirmationsController` .

**edit:**
Admin creates user with just name and email.

Answer (score 2):

In User model add `confirmable`

```
devise :confirmable
```

Generate migration by this command

```
rails g migration add_confirmable_to_devise
```

In migration file add this and run `rake db:migrate`

```
class AddConfirmableToDevise < ActiveRecord::Migration
  # Note: You can't use change, as User.update_all with fail in the down migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :confirmation_token, :string
    add_column :users, :confirmed_at, :datetime
    add_column :users, :confirmation_sent_at, :datetime
    # add_column :users, :unconfirmed_email, :string # Only if using reconfirmable
    add_index :users, :confirmation_token, :unique => true
    # User.reset_column_information # Need for some types of updates, but not for update_all.
    # To avoid a short time window between running the migration and updating all existing
    # users as confirmed, do the following
    User.update_all(:confirmed_at => Time.now)
    # All existing user accounts should be able to log in after this.
  end

  def self.down
    remove_columns :users, :confirmation_token, :confirmed_at, :confirmation_sent_at
    # remove_columns :users, :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable
  end
end
```

On signup devise will automatically send confirmation email with instructions

Source - [https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Add-%3aconfirmable-to-Users)

Comment: `devise :confirmable` is what I had missed. Now I get Password can't be blank issue, can I override with any method?

Comment: Are you signing up without password?

Comment: You need to override default signup then, create a random password while creating the user, in the confirmation email send that password to user along with the confirmation link

Comment: I could do that without`:confirmable`. I need user to set-up his initial password through link itself, is it possible with devise?

Comment: Create a controller and override the default behaviour, its not predefined